# Templates can be used only with field access, property access in Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I got this error when I was creating a Edit and Templating for `Product`.

```
Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.
```

**Edit** In my Razor View:

```
 <p>
  @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table>
    <tr>
    <th>
      @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Select(m => m.ProductID))
    </th>
    <th>
      @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Select(m => m.Name))
    </th>
    <th>
      @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Select(m => m.ListPrice))
    </th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
  <tr>
    <td>
      @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductID)
    </td>
    <td>
      @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
    </td>
    <td>
      @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ListPrice)
    </td>
    <td>
      @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ProductID }) |
      @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ProductID }) |
      @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ProductID })
    </td>
  </tr>
}
</table>
```

Do you know what that mean and how to fix it? Thank you so much!

Comment: Do you want to generate a `<th>` for each `ProductID` in your model?

Comment: @TrungPham For what reason? It's simple table with header, it will never normally work with this 3 selects. What you expect as result? `DisplayFor` for `Enumerable<>`?

Answer (score 0):

doesnt this just work?

```
<th> @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ProductID) </th>
```

edit, try something like this:

```
<table id="myTable">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ProductID)
        </th>
    </tr>
     @foreach (var item in Model)                     
       {    
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductID)
            </td>
            <td>
              @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductID)
            </td>
         </tr>
        }
</table>
```

Comment: can you show the declaration of your model? is it an IEnumerable or not ?

Comment: `@model IEnumerable<AdventureCycle.Models.Product>` here it is, Thousand!

Comment: you need to show more code in that case, you need a foreach() to go over your model

Comment: I just edited it. I put in a `foreach()`, it still got an error.

Comment: you need to get rid of that .Select, try removing this part "    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Select(m => m.ProductID))" and just put in something like "ProductID" to see if it works then

Comment: It didn't show `ProductID`, just show something like `Select` query, @Thousand!